# Sublime text 3 not recognizing html files when using templates

Tags: sublimetext3

Can't seem to find the exact problem elsewhere...

Basically in my html file at the top I have:

`<%inherit file="base.html"/>`

This proceeds to screw up all the highlighting in the file and also confuses the commenting shortcut.

This:

[image]

Changes into this:

[image]

Comment: How does it screw up the highlighting? Does it pick a different syntax than HTML on load? What happens when you try to comment? What happens if you manually choose the HTML syntax? Please [edit] your question with these details. Also, a screenshot would be quite valuable.

Comment: @MattDMo Added. On a side note, your comment makes me think perhaps a plugin is causing the error if it's not a typical problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Wasn't aware that this was using Mako as the templating system rather than a more well known one. This package allows you to set the syntax at HTML(Mako)

https://github.com/OmeGak/sublime-text-user-settings

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `<%blabla>` and `</%blabla>` are not considered closed.

I'm using a workaround like this: line 4 will close line 1

```
1 <%block name="content">
2 <%
3 #
4 %>
5 <div>
6 Syntax highlight as before. Emmet works too.
7 </div> 
8 </%block>
```